# Wordpress - insert custom content in get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress

I rarely work with Wordpress and PHP so this one has me a bit stumped. I am working on a client site, which is using `get_template_part(template)` where the template is a default template created and maintained by the client.

I've been asked to insert an image to a section that does not normally contain an image without modifying the template, however I can insert basic html into a simple array element such as `copy`. `<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">` works fine, as an example, however I need to use `theme_file_uri` for the source.

I have tried

```
array(
   'copy' => '<img src="' echo theme_file_uri(/..) '">' 
)
```

and

```
array(
   'copy' => '<img src="'?><?php echo theme_file_uri(/..) ?><?php'">' 
)
```

and even just `'copy' => '<img src="'?><?php ?><?php'">'` just to test if breaking it in the middle of the php script would work (it did not).

I am stumped, and need to figure out how to insert this dynamic path for the image into this preexisting template. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate one string to another, use the `.` operator:

```
array(
   'copy' => '<img src="' . get_theme_file_uri(/..) . '">' 
)
```

Comment: Ah man, that did it. Thought it was some voodoo logic I didn't understand, just turns out I forgot something as simple as how to do concatenation in php. Thanks!